# How can I export an Unity project to a Hololens if I am developing in a Remote desk connection?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-desktop, hololens

I am using a virtual machine (remote desk connection .rdp) to create an application in Unity and I want to test my process in a Hololens but I can't export the Visual Studio solution via USB or remote because the remote desk can´t find the Hololens even if I check all the local resources.

Does anyone know if it is possible to export to the Hololens using a Remote desk? or 
Another way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the HoloLens to the local network via Wifi and setup visual studio on your remote machine to connect to the hololens via the address that is assigned to it.